# PayPal Adaptive Payments ConvertCurrency

Tags: paypal

I am try to run the ConvertCurrency Adaptive Payments but can't find any sample code that doesn't use the SDK so I'm looking at the PDF from PayPal but I'm still confused.  What format should these be in:

baseAmountList ap:CurrencyList
convertToCurrencyList ap:CurrencyCodeList
requestEnvelope common:RequestEnvelope

I have no idea what they mean by ap:CurrencyList.  This doesn't work:

baseAmountList=".array( 'amount' => 15, 'code' => 'USD' )

So how should it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be XML.  Here's a sample request and response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConvertCurrencyRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <baseAmountList xmlns="">
    <currency xmlns=""><code xmlns="">USD</code>
      <amount xmlns="">100.00</amount>
    </currency>
  </baseAmountList>
  <convertToCurrencyList xmlns="">
    <currencyCode xmlns="">EUR</currencyCode>
    <currencyCode xmlns="">AUD</currencyCode>
    <currencyCode xmlns="">CAD</currencyCode>
  </convertToCurrencyList>
</ConvertCurrencyRequest>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:ConvertCurrencyResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <responseEnvelope>
    <timestamp>2013-12-19T23:22:07.832-08:00</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <correlationId>0d0f271253d3c</correlationId>
    <build>7935900</build>
  </responseEnvelope>
  <estimatedAmountTable>
    <currencyConversionList>
      <baseAmount><code>USD</code>
        <amount>100.00</amount>
      </baseAmount>
      <currencyList>
        <currency><code>EUR</code>
          <amount>73.39</amount>
        </currency>
        <currency><code>AUD</code>
          <amount>105.41</amount>
        </currency>
        <currency><code>CAD</code>
          <amount>100.76</amount>
        </currency>
      </currencyList>
    </currencyConversionList>
  </estimatedAmountTable>
</ns2:ConvertCurrencyResponse>
```

Comment: Sorry Andrew I didn't know you'd made a comment seeing as they don't notify me via email here.  How do I give you points, that again is not clear.

Comment: Click the up arrow to the left of my answer, and then you should also have a way to accept it as the final answer.